# How to login with cURL with POST and Cookie

Tags: php, forms, cookies, curl, authentication

The server successfully receives login, password and CAPTCHA. How do I do it with a cookie?

I don't know what info is needed for help i'll show all:

Login Form:

```
<div id="loginForm">
 <div id="logo"><img src="logo.png" border="0" /></div>
 <div class="loginBar">Login</div>
  <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="p" value="login" />
    <div class="line">
      <label>Captcha</label>
      <img src="captcha/securimage_show.php" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="text" name="captcha" value=""/>                
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
  </form>                        
 <hr/>
 <a href="index.php?p=register" class="register" title="Click to register">Register</a>
</div>
```

cURL code:

```
    extract($_POST);

    //set POST variables
    $proxy = '127.0.0.1:8118';
    $url = 'http://example.com/index.php';
    $fields_string= 'p=login&user=' . $user . '&pass=' . $passwd . '&captcha=' . $_POST['captcha'] . '&submit=Login';

        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        print_r(curl_error($ch));
        print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
        print_r(curl_errno($ch));

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);
```

curl getinfo:

```
[url] => http://example.com/index.php 
[content_type] => text/html 
[http_code] => 200 
[header_size] => 415 
[request_size] => 325 
[filetime] => -1 
[ssl_verify_result] => 0 
[redirect_count] => 0 
[total_time] => 1.549389 
[namelookup_time] => 3.7E-5 
[connect_time] => 0.000138 
[pretransfer_time] => 0.000142 
[size_upload] => 62 
[size_download] => 1585 
[speed_download] => 1022 
[speed_upload] => 40 
[download_content_length] => 1585 
[upload_content_length] => 0 
[starttransfer_time] => 1.27051 
[redirect_time] => 0 
[certinfo] => Array ( ) 
[redirect_url] =>
```

Real cookie:

```
Host:                 example.com
Name:                 PHPSESSID
Path:                 /
Content:              7qk7bb17nr030g5j59h2gq3nq6
Content raw:          7qk7bb17nr030g5j59h2gq3nq6
Expires:              At end of session
Expires raw:          0
Send for:             Any type of connection
Send for raw:         false
Created:              Fri 25 Nov 2011 10:37:24 PM EET
Created raw:          1322253443569272
Last accessed:        Sat 26 Nov 2011 11:06:02 AM EET
Last accessed raw:    1322298361723991
HTTP only:            No
HTTP only raw:        false
This domain only:     No
This domain only raw: false
Policy:               no information available
Policy raw:           0
Status:               no information available
Status raw:           0
---
```

Gerenated file by libcurl in cookie.txt:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

example.com FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   crs9cm100agdfsujsncr964jg7
```

When i run this code, Account, Passwd and Captcha successfull is received by server, but have error with cookie:

> Make sure you've cookies enabled

Also i saw that real cookie Content raw is different by generated with libcurl.

Also i saw that from my form i successful catch the webserver cookie.

PS!! I receive cookie from this link in login form:

```
  <img src="captcha/securimage_show.php" border="0" />
```

Comment: Wasn't this exact same question asked earlier today? Looks like the original question was deleted. Just wondering what happened to it because it's obviously the same exact question and source.

Comment: nobody response.. i just tried to find some tips( but also nosuccess.

Comment: Have you tried just posting your data to the target site directly, rather than using CURL (IE, wrap your form in form tags and make the target the target URL "http://example.com/index.php")?

Answer (score 1):

It could be cause of the missing attribute

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
```

This way curl will be forced to ignore 'old' session cookies and start a new session instead.

Comment: with this parameter also reveice 2 deferent cookie.
1. in cookie.txt and 2. real cookie.