# how to use cookies and postfields with libcurl in C?

Tags: c, cookies, libcurl

When I do

```
curl --get --cookie-jar mycookie.cookie http://mypage/page/
```

it will store a cookie as `mycookie.cookie`

and then when I do

```
curl --cookie mycookie.cookie --data "field1=field1" --data "field2=field2" --data csrfmiddlewaretoken=(csrf token) http://mypage/page/register/
```

the `csrf token` I get through a cat `mycookie.cookie` and fill it manually in.

This works. It does what I want.

So now I want to use libcurl with `C` to do this. Following the doc I have this:

```
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl) {

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, http://mypage/page/);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "");  
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST, &cookies);

   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, http://mypage/page/register/);

   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookies);

   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "field1=field1;field1=field1;csrfmiddlewaretoken=(csrf token)");

   res = curl_easy_perform(curl);


    printf("Erasing curl's knowledge of cookies!\n");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIELIST, "ALL");
    curl_slist_free_all(cookies);
 }
  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
```

So this will pass the cookie but throw an error for missing fields. So I thought this line will post all the fields:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "field1=field1;field1=field1;csrfmiddlewaretoken=(csrf token)");
```

I also tried passing all the fields through this line:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookies);
```

by riding everything in a `char array`

I also tried replacing `,` with `;` but nothing works.

I don't think I wrote anything wrong, it looks more like the post overwrite each other, because if I run the programm without the `COOKIEFILE` line it says missing cookie.

Any idea, how I post all necessary pieces information?

**EDIT**

Ok, I got it to work through these two posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699329/php-post-request-with-curl-and-cookie) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281815/how-to-login-with-curl-with-post-and-cookie) and Daniel Stenberg

So I have the same code just without

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, cookies);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your string sent to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is different than the string your command line uses! When you use `--data` multiple times, curl will concatenate the strings with an ampersand (&) in between, while your C code uses a semicolon.
2. You pass the wrong input to CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE. It accepts a file name, nothing else. But you don't need to use that option in your second request, since you enabled the "cookie engine" in the first request, all cookies recieved in the first request are kept in the curl handle and will be used in the subsequent request anyway when reusing the handle.
3. To extract the `csrf_token` cookie, you would use the `CURLINFO_COOKIELIST` and parse through the list of cookies to find it, extract the contents and use that in the subsequent POST request.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer and got it to work, thanks to your answer, however, I am not using the second `COOKIEFILE` line. Is that what you meant? Not sure how to get this without the `CURLINFO_COOKIELIST` line, because in this one I am extracting the csrf token ?

Comment: or is that what you meant?

Comment: I changed the (3) part, as you would still need to extract all the cookies to find the one you want and then add that cookie content to the POST you send